# Linq groupby performance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

in a mvc project i am using this method. However, when the database getting bigger and bigger, it is being very slow . How can i solve that ?

```
    private  List<SelectListItem> getDates() {
        var db = new _Entities();
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var date = db.Location
                   .GroupBy(k => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(k.DateServer))
                   .ToList();
        //var date = db.Location.Select(m => m.DateService).Distinct();
        foreach (var x in date) 
        {
            list.Add(
              new SelectListItem 
              { 
                Value = x.FirstOrDefault().DateServer.Date.ToShortDateString(), 
                Text = x.FirstOrDefault().DateServer.ToShortDateString() 
              } );
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: By the way, the text and the value are the same since you are grouping by date.

Comment: Might need to see what query is bring produced by whatever solution is presented. Based on that your database might need an index as well.

Comment: You realiye it takes more time to group more data. Unless you made a beginner mistake (missing index - jikes) - that is a fact. So the trick is to filter the data before the group by. Or get better hardware. Or cache results in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create a list and a loop but use the database:

```
return db.Location.GroupBy(k => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(k.DateServer))
    .Select(group => new { group, first = group.First() })
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { 
        Value = x.first.DateServer.Date.ToShortDateString(), 
        Text  = x.first.DateServer.ToShortDateString() 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Since you are grouping by date the text and the value are the same, so it could be simplified:

```
return db.Location.GroupBy(k => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(k.DateServer))
    .Select(g => new SelectListItem { Value = g.Key.ToShortDateString(), Value = g.Key.ToShortDateString() })
    .ToList();
```